# Using eval to print quoted string in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use `eval` to print a string containing quotes. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str_with_double_quotes = 'Hello "world"!';
my $str_with_single_quotes = "Hello 'world'!";
my $str_with_quotes = "Hello \"'world'\"!";

say "1. $str_with_double_quotes";
say "2. $str_with_single_quotes";
say "3. $str_with_quotes";

my $cmd1 = "say 'a: $str_with_double_quotes'";
my $cmd2 = "say \"b: $str_with_single_quotes\"";
my $cmd3 = "say 'c: $str_with_quotes'";

eval($cmd1);
eval($cmd2);
eval($cmd3);
```

This works for case 1 and case 2, but not for case 3, since the string contains both single and double quotes. Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the singl quotes too?

Comment: @Jens No.. but in the real code the string is input as a variable to a sub routine, so I cannot just manually insert backslashes as in this question. I think I would have to write some code to scan the string for quotes..

Comment: use regex for this. `$string =~ s/\'/\\\'/g` and `$string =~ s/\"/\\\"/g`

Comment: @Jens Thanks!! I think this should work for the general case: `$str =~ s/\"/\\\"/g; eval("say \"$str\"");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the `q` (equivalent to single quotes) and `qq` (equivalent to double quotes) operators:

```
my $str_with_quotes = qq(Hello "'world'"!);
my $cmd3 = qq(say q(c: $str_with_quotes));
```

Note that, when using `q`/`qq`, you do *not* escape any single/double quotes in the string.